# What exactly are user ports?

Tags: networking, port

I was a little confused
I noticed that:

**Well-known ports**, are predefined ports on servers that are used to connect the client to the server. (that reserved in IANA)

**Dynamic ports**, are ports that the client temporarily selects at random to communicate with the server. (they are not reserved at IANA)

But I do not know exactly what user ports are. I only know about them that they are reserved in IANA by certain entities for certain services but if so, what is the difference between well-known ports and them?

Answer (score 4):

**[Well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports)** ports are defined as ports with their number **less than 1024**. Listening on these ports is usually allowed only to processes running as superuser (root in Linux terminology, see below).

Ports with higher number, also known as [**user ports** or **registered ports**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Registered_ports) are ports **in range 1024–49151** and any user can listen on them.

This restriction are typically enforced on Unix-like systems.

And finally, highest-numbered ports, **in range 49152–65535** are typically used only for temporary connections. They are usually assigned to client applications. These ports are called [**ephemeral** or **dynamic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

---

## Few words about superusers

[**Superuser account**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) (not to be confused with [this Q&A site](https://superuser.com)), usually known as `root`, sometimes with alternaive names such as `toor` is on Unix-like operating systems (Linux, BSD-like systems etc.) the user account that has allowed to do everything and minimal restrictions are imposed to it. It is defined by having **[UID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) set to 0** This user account is similar to Windows administrator account.

This user is allowed to listen (or more precisely *bind*) on ports below 1024 and therefore it is allowed to provide services on well-known ports. Many programs that need to use this port number run as root (but they usually switch their user for other work than networking). This limitation should prevent ordinary users from pretending to be owner of the machine that can provide “well-known” services such as SSH (port 22), HTTP(S) (ports 80, 443), FTP and others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Only if possible, can you give an explanation about the super user?

Comment: @user2, ok, wait a moment…

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia
[Registered port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_port)
lists all the kinds of ports and their various names:

> Ports with numbers 0–1023 are called system or well-known ports; ports
> with numbers 1024-49151 are called user or registered ports, and ports
> with numbers 49152-65535 are called dynamic, private or ephemeral
> ports.[2] Both system and user ports are used by transport protocols
> (TCP, UDP, DCCP, SCTP) to identify an application or service.
>
> - **Ports 0–1023** – system or well-known ports
> - **Ports 1024–49151 – user or registered ports**
> - **Ports 49152–65535** – dynamic / private / ephemeral ports

Answer (score 0):

[IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) has the following definition:

> Port numbers are assigned in various ways, based on three ranges:
> System Ports (0-1023), User Ports (1024-49151), and the Dynamic
> and/or Private Ports (49152-65535); the difference uses of these
> ranges is described in [[RFC6335](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6335)].

The differentiation is mainly for IANAs approval policies, but of course it also means that operating systems use the number ranges as default.

Terms like „Well-known“ ports are a bit more muddy, but usually mean all ports in the IANA registry or the /etc/services file.

Some operating systems (like windows) do not have the concept of priveledged ports and some operating systems allow to configure the dynamic port range or reserve an extra range for PAT (like Linux) in the private range.

If you talk about a port where a unprivileged user(as opposed to priveledges root process) can listen on a port I would not use the term user port (for exactly the confusion which is behind the original question).